# PHP - mssql - mssql_get_last_message() returns empty string

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, error-handling

Why does the php function [mssql_get_last_message()](http://php.net/mssql_get_last_message) sometimes return empty string instead of the complete real error, despite the query failing?

What can I do to get the real and complete error?

Comment: change mssql.... to mysql?

Comment: @MartHaarman Unlikely. He's using Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice

Answer (score 0):

It could be a timeout I've had this problem but not been able to confirm it timeout can be adjusted in php.ini

```
mssql.timeout = 120;
```